# Append new Property to existing JSON object on click event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am trying to append value from a input field into an existng JSON object and I keep getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
$('#addObjectBtn').click(function() {
            //Inject Property into current object
            var newObjName = $('#newObjectName').val();
            var newObjType = $('#newObjectType').val();
            objStr.View[newObjType + "_100"] = {"BackgroundImage":'""' + newObjName + '""'};
            $('#newObjectPrompt').dialog('close');
        })
```

EDIT: ADD JSON Object. I am trying to add for example another Button. Which would be "Button_100" in my example

```
{
    "View": {
        "Name": "Untitled3",
        "ImportWidth": 320,
        "ImportHeight": 480,
        "Image_1": {
            "BackgroundImage": "Image.png",
            "Position": [0, 0],
            "Width": 320,
            "Height": 480
        },
        "Button_1": {
            "BackgroundImage": "ButtonTop.png",
            "Position": [61, 83],
            "Width": 217,
            "Height": 58
        },
        "Button_2": {
            "BackgroundImage": "ButtonBottom.png",
            "Position": [81, 114],
            "Width": 205,
            "Height": 73
        },
        "TextField_1": {
            "BackgroundImage": "TextFieldLogin.png",
            "Position": [102, 336],
            "Width": 189,
            "Height": 31
        },
        "Label_1": {
            "Position": [137, 100],
            "Width": 54,
            "Height": 20,
            "Text": "HiRob",
            "FontSize": 18,
            "Color": [0, 0, 0, 1]
        },
        "Label_2": {
            "Position": [43, 342],
            "Width": 72,
            "Height": 20,
            "Text": "LogOut:",
            "FontSize": 18,
            "Color": [0, 0, 0, 1]
        },
        "Label_3": {
            "Position": [115, 234],
            "Width": 126,
            "Height": 20,
            "Text": "AnotherButton",
            "FontSize": 18,
            "Color": [0, 0, 0, 1]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If only we knew what the errors were!

Comment: It would be better if you know what error message is it. You can try to debug by showing the value of objStr object on the UI. Are you sure it has the property 'View', and the 'objStr.View' is an object or maybe it's a string or number? Another tip to show the error on the mobile webview: try{} catch(e){alert(e)}

Comment: Change `{"BackgroundImage":'""' + newObjName + '""'}` to this - `{ BackgroundImage : newObjName }`, mentioned in the answer below

Comment: @BlueSmith I am able to target `ImportWidth` by using `objStr.View. ImportWidth`. so I assume it should be accessible

Comment: @OmShankar typo.. I am able to target ImportWidth by using objStr.View. ImportWidth. so I assume it should be accessible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
objStr.View[newObjName + "_100"] = JQuery.phraseJSON('{"BackgroundImage":"' + newObjType +'"}');
```

Using phraseJSON is kind of round about, but it will definately get the job done, it converts a JSON string into a JS object.

EDIT:
newObjType is already a string

Alternatively, without JQuery JSON.parse(string) can be used.

Comment: here is what I used but no dice `objStr.View[newObjType + "_100"] = JQuery.phraseJSON('{"BackgroundImage":' + newObjName + '}');`

Comment: I wonder why this answer works and the one by Darin does not, since `JSON.parse('{"BackgroundImage":"' + newObjType +'"}')` is the same object as `{BackgroundImage: newObjType}`

Answer (score 5):

`newObjType` is already a string, you don't need all those quotes. Try like this:

```
objStr.View[newObjName + "_100"] = {BackgroundImage: newObjType};
```

Comment: It would have been far more helpful to explain what error message you are getting rather than saying *it just failed*.

Comment: Sorry, I would but I do not get a console as this is being built in a web view of a native mobile. Very few debug abilities

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

In the absence of debugging tools on mobile, I would recommend [**WEINRE**](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). It gives you same console and other stuff in Desktop for application running on mobile

Also, looking at your comment, seems the error is somewhere else. You can optionally try this way of assigning

```
var newObjName = $('#newObjectName').val();
var newObjType = $('#newObjectType').val();
var tempObj = {"BackgroundImage": newObjName };
objStr.View[newObjType + "_100"] = tempObj;
```

---

**OLD Answer**:

I suppose the error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
And I suppose that is caused by `{"BackgroundImage":'""' + newObjName + '""'};`
And your way of setting property in the code is also erroneous

As a correction, I think you need to do 2 changes

Change your code from:

```
{"BackgroundImage":'""' + newObjName + '""'}
```

To

```
{ BackgroundImage : newObjName }
```

Cool, isn't it ??